# Is decoder 2-4 a complete system?

Tags: flipflop

Is decoder 2-4 a complete system?

My opinion: You can create OR, AND with D0-D3(For example D3 = X * Y). but you can't create NOT, because you do not have zero. for example {Dec 2-4,0} IS a complete system.

What do you guys think?

Edit: **What I mean by complete system**: it will be able to create "NOT" and one of these two: "OR" or "AND"

Comment: A definition of "complete system" would be nice.

Comment: @uint128_t Complete system: Given input values, for example "A,B", if you plug them to a certain system, you can get {Not} and {Or} or {And}. For example NOR is a complete system because you can create NOT and OR. NAND is a complete system because you can create NOT and AND. so NOT is required. and then you need atleast one: AND or OR.

Comment: The more common term is [functional completeness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).

Comment: @uint128_t I see. what do u think about: if I enter {a,a}, in D0 i get a', if i enter {a, b} i get a*b from D3. which means it is a functional completeness?

Comment: NOR and NAND are both functionally complete. If you can make either of those with your decoder, then you have something which is functionally complete. I'll let you see if this is possible.

Comment: @TomCarpenter NOR: if I enter F{a,b} I get = (A + B)' -> A'B'. if I enter F{a,b} to Dec 2-4. I get in D0 A'B'. Thus it's func. complete?

Comment: There you go then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a gate/module/system to be [Functionally Complete](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness), it must be possible to make any logic gate from a combination of this gate/module/system.

NAND is a standard example of functional completeness as it is possible to make all gates from a network of NAND gates. The same is true for NOR gates.

To prove functional completeness of a system, you either need to show a way in which every other gate can be made from this system, or show that you can make a NAND gate or a NOR gate from your system. The former proves it the long winded way, the latter proves it by relying on the knowledge that NAND/NOR are complete.

In your case, for a 2-4 Decoder, it is possible to make a NOR gate. The output \$D_0\$ is the NOR of the inputs \$A\$ and \$B\$. Therefore a 2-4 decoder is functionally complete.

Comment: Thank you for the time sir., Electronics is such a beautiful subject, but I study CS :(